# Why does the program take so long to run?

Tags: python

I'm trying to solve a question from Project Euler using Python. Why does my code take so long to run when the range of j is huge. It works just fine when j has a small range.

[image]

Comment: [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: As Andreas has highlighted, it's better to paste code as a code block. Code can then be copied/pasted into a chosen python environment.

Comment: Also, the picture may not even display well on some devices, or have a colour scheme that people with vision issues are unable to read.

Answer (score 2):

since your program has 2 for loops that fully iterate, your program time complexity is O(n**2) so it is expected to take so long time, you can do some optimizations in your code:

```
import math

def is_prime(number):
    for i in range(2, int(math.sqrt(number) + 1)):               
       if (number % i) == 0: 
           return False
    return True
```

Comment: The function would consider 4 as a prime number as well

Comment: @PapattaradaApithanangsiri check now

Comment: I'm just curious, why would the initial function consider 4 as a prime number?

Comment: well, because the range(2, 4//2) is the same with range(2, 2) so there is no number generated by the range function, the for  loop it is not executed and the function returns true

Answer (score 0):

Think about it logically, the larger the range, larger the number of iterations/loops for j. And then again the larger each individual number of j gets which is fed in to is_prime, the larger the i loop gets as well. Thus compounding the length of time it takes to run.

Your i loop needs to be smarter. Is there a need to check any more i numbers are factors of j once count its larger than 2? ;)